# compare two large files to reconciliate financial transactions

Tags: file, hadoop, mapreduce, compare

I am trying to write a program  to compare two large files: two files should compare financial transactions every day. files can be xml or csv format.
there are between 3 and 4 million lines per file and fifty columns. Reconciliation occurs on the basis of an area defined by a set of key fields.

output must identify rows with the same key but where data is different

I used SQL comparison (each file in a table), it works but it requires a database such as Oracle and a powerful server

t there is a solution using MapReduce concepts or bases nosql

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a problem to do a daily comparison of 2 3-4m indexed tables in any rdbms (oracle, sql server, mysql, postgre) for that matter and it wouldn't take too long too.

You may use a MapReduce based data processing system such as Hadoop to do the same as well. There are a few Hadoop-as-a-service platforms out there including ours (Xplenty) which can help you do it quickly and with pay-per-use pricing so that you can lower your costs to do this type of processing. I wouldn't recommend using a MapReduce based solution for a simple comparison of a few million records but if the comparison is complex then you may give it a try.